# Twitter Developer and Visualizations

Tags: r, twitter, data-mining

I am trying to create visualizations through R. I've created a new project in the twitter developer, have my secret API keys, and can pull up tweets on Twitter when I search.

```
Soccer <- search_tweets ("World Cup", n=50, include_rts =FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how I can create visualizations with this information? I am also extremely new at R so any help would be appreciated.

I tried following tutorials online but I keep getting multiple error messages.

Comment: [here](https://www.raynamharris.com/blog/sacnas_rtweet/) a tutorial that might give you some ideas.

Comment: Please read these guidelines and edit your question to address the points suggested therein: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Here's a book of different visualization examples using rtweet data: https://rud.is/books/21-recipes/ and https://github.com/hrbrmstr/21-recipes